# How can I save a plot in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using:

```
In [42]: tz_counts[:10].plot(kind='barh', rot=0)
```

it return:

```
Out[42]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7fa216b464d0>
```

But I can't see any file, it isn't showing either.

I start learning python today. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: you try save the plot as a image ? like a png ?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
plt.savefig('a.pdf')
```

Comment: @TiagoBruno Please consider accepting it as the answer by clicking the 'tick' on the left if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I am waiting the minimum time required to accept an answer. You can accept an answer in 20 seconds.